# Embedded div tags - no image load

Tags: html, css

I think this will be a simple fix for someone out there!

CSS:

```
#partners .social{
    width:219.5px;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
}

#partners .social .social-logo{
    width:61px;
    height:61px;
    float:left;
}

#partners .social .social-text{
    width:158.5px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="social">
    <div class="social-logo"
        <img src="images/fb-silver.png" alt="Find us on Facebook!" />
    </div>
    <div class="social-text">
        Find us on Facebook
    </div>
 </div>
```

The image 'fb-silver.png' won't display.

I've tried to load the image outside of these tags and it's fine.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Well, you're missing a closing `>` on the parent (`.social-logo`) div. If that's the copied HTML then you've got, so far as a browser is concerned, ***very*** badly-mangled HTML.

Comment: You don't have closing `>` for the `div` element..

Comment: Typo in your original code (meaning it's working now) or in copying the code here? (meaning it's still not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your DIV, also half a pixel doesnt exist i think...
If this doesnt work, the url to your image will be wrong!

```
<div class="social">

    <div class="social-logo">

        <img src="images/fb-silver.png" alt="Find us on Facebook!" />
    </div>
    <div class="social-text">
        Find us on Facebook
    </div>
 </div>
```